Time clauses and how to use them with different tenses

"While, when" after those words in time clauses we are allowed to use either present simple, continuous or perfect. Let me provide some examples.

a. Lets's talk when I finish work ( after I did my work)
b. Let's talk when I have finished work ( also after I did my work but using this tense we emphasize completion)
c. Let's talk when I'm finishing work ( during the time of me completing my work, not after)

"After, before" with those words we are only allowed to use present simple or perfect. Present continuous isn't used here.

a. Do it after  he comes
b. Do it after he has come ( a and b have the same meaning)
c. Do it after he is coming ( wrong, doesn't really make sense)

"the moment, as long as, once, until, by the time, as soon as" with all of them I can use present perfect and simple. I don't know what about present continuous. I will provide some examples and tell me if they make sense.

a. the moment/ once/ by the time/ as soon as he is entering the living room we scream "happy birthday" ( can we use all those words the same way as "when plus continuous" to show during his entering not after or no and only "when, while" may be used that way?)
b.as long as you work vs you are working ( here I think both versions are fine. The continuous one implies some current situation. Simple one is more general. correct?
In conlusion, please check if my 1 and 2 point is correct and answer questions in point 3.

Yes, (1) and (2) are correct.  As for (3a), I would find The moment he enters the room much more idiomatic. By the time doesn't really fit this context. By the time he finally came into the living room, we had almost begun to think he would never appear.

@Kate Bunting. Could you also comment on "once, as soon as" and point b, please?

By singling out by the time, I meant to imply that the three other options were all OK (with the simple present tense).  Yes, I agree with Adam's comment on  (3b).

@Kate Bunting. Thank you.Can you imaginr using "until" with a continuous tense and sayinh something like "don't book a spa until everything is working"? Does it make sense?

@trainbee282 - Yes, that makes sense (assuming that you mean that the facilities at the spa may not all be working yet).
